# MongoDB Compass create TTL index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to create a TTL index using mongo db compass.

My document is as follows

[image]

I created the following index in mongo db compass.
[image]

But the ttl index doesn't seem to take effect on the existing or the new entries in the document.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Compass are you using?

I tried that with a field of type Date and it worked well: the document was gone after the TTL expired. Have you checked in the shell if the index is properly created with a TTL? You should see something like this:

```
> db.boo.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.boo"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "date" : 1
        },
        "name" : "date_1",
        "ns" : "test.boo",
        "background" : false,
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 600
    }
]
```